# Looping through LinkedLinkst in two places gives error

Tags: java, linked-list, iteration

So I am making a little game in Java, and in the game you have Entities which are stored in a LinkedList. In the tick method I iterate through the Entities' LinkedList like this:

```
@Override
public void tick(float delta) {
    for (Entity e : entities) {
        e.tick(delta);
    }
    player.tick(delta);
}
```

And the same for the render method

```
@Override
public void render(Graphics g) {
    g.setColor(Color.DARK_GRAY);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, Game.WIDTH, Game.HEIGHT);
    for(Entity e : entities) {
        e.render(g);
    }
    player.render(g);
}
```

One of the Entities is a class called Block. And in the Block class there is a function which returns if a block is near, in this function I also iterate through the Entities' LinkedList and it's called from the following tick method in Block:

```
    @Override
public void tick(float delta) {
    if (color == Color.WHITE) {
        if (getSurrounding(-32, -32) != null && getSurrounding(-32, -32).getColor() == Color.BLACK) {
            if (getSurrounding(-32, -32).getStrength() < strength) {
                getSurrounding(-32, -32).setStrength(-50);
            }
        }
    }

    if (!inGame.entities.isEmpty() && strength <= 0) {
        inGame.entities.remove(this); // <------ REMOVING AN ELEMENT
    }
}

public Block getSurrounding(int xOffset, int yOffset) {
    for (Entity e : inGame.entities) {
        if (e instanceof Block) {
            if (x + xOffset == e.getX() && y + yOffset == e.getY()) {
                return (Block) e;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

(This function is called and used in the tick method of the block by the way)

Now everytime I run the game, the game starts and runs normal for a couple milliseconds and then it throws this exception:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.LinkedList$ListItr.checkForComodification(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.LinkedList$ListItr.next(Unknown Source)
    at _47b3n.game.engine.gamestate.gamestates.InGame.tick(InGame.java:36)
    at _47b3n.game.engine.Handler.tick(Handler.java:17)
    at _47b3n.game.engine.Game.tick(Game.java:70)
    at _47b3n.game.engine.Game.run(Game.java:52)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

(The first two code samples are in the InGame.java file, and line 36 is the for-loop in the tick method)
Now how do I stop this error?

Comment: don't remove elements from list while iterating them.

Comment: @hellzone that is not completly true. if he would use an `Iterator`, it would work

Comment: @hellzone it doesnt look appear that the poster is deleting anything

Comment: @hellzone I am only removing elements in the tick method of the block after iterating etc. So that wouldn't be a problem right?

Comment: obviously it is, otherwise you wouldn't get the exception

Comment: @JohnKane I am only removing elements in the tick method of the block after iterating etc.

Comment: Do you modify `inGame` at any point while a `tick` may happen?

Comment: @XtremeBaumer I'll add the part where I am removing elements

Comment: Can you post code from InGame.java from line 30 to 40?

Comment: you are most probably still iterating the list somewhere in your code at the moment you want to modify the list

Comment: @C-Otto No inGame is defined in the constructor of Block

Comment: @RishikeshDhokare i added it

Comment: the very first code block you posted is most probably the problem. there you iterate the list and call the `tick` method which deletes elements

Comment: @XtremeBaumer yes the exception refers to InGame.java:36 which is indeed the first code block

Comment: Not only use an [`Iterator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html), but also use its [`remove`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#remove--) method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`ConcurrentModificationException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html) usually relates to modifying the list while iterating through it within a loop.

My assumption is that you are removing an element while you are iterating through.

In order to stop this from happening, i would recommend saving the object you want to delete in a variable while it is in the loop (and has met some condition), then removing it from the list after the loop has completed.

Edit: based on the updated question, you are removing an element within the tick method. I would not do this here, but return the element that you would like to remove and remove it only when you are no longer iterating the list you are removing from.

**Possible solution:**
I would create another method to check the strength of the Entity and calling that from the tick method (this is to save the tick method having to return an object to delete) as so:

```
@Override
public void tick(float delta) {
    Entity removeEntity = null;
    for (Entity e : entities) {
        e.tick(delta);
        if(e.checkStrength()){
           removeEntity = e;
           break;
        }
    }

    if(removeEntity != null){
       entities.remove(removeEntity);
    }

    player.tick(delta);
}
```

In the entity class:

```
public boolean checkStrength(){
    if (!inGame.entities.isEmpty() && strength <= 0) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Just so you know this is not the best solution by far, but should get you through the problem you have now. Be sure to clean your code up when you have time.

Comment: Or just use an `Iterator`

Comment: @XtremeBaumer I already tried an Iterator but it doesn't work, it gave the same error

Comment: I have now added code where I actually remove something from the LinkedList

Comment: @XtremeBaumer it's not clear to me why you think using an Iterator would make a difference (and I consider myself an experienced Java programmer). A for-each loop effectively uses an iterator "under the hood" anyway. Am I missing something?

Comment: @davmac from the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html) `Iterators allow the caller to remove elements from the underlying collection during the iteration with well-defined semantics.`

Comment: @RubendeGroot i have just added an edit referring to your updated question, i hope it helps!

Comment: @XtremeBaumer that means you can use a single iterator to iterate through a collection and remove elements. It does not mean you can iterate through the collection using two iterators simultaneously (nor one iterator and one for-each loop) and delete elements using one of the iterators. I suppose that you are saying the two loops can be reduced to a single loop with a single iterator but that is unclear from your comment.

Comment: @davmac since he is not using multiple threads, he wont have 2 iterators iterating the same collection. whenever you get a `ConcurrentModificationException` in single threaded environment, then a properly used `Iterator` is the solution.

Comment: @XtremeBaumer right, I've gotten mixed up here. The point is you have to remove the item through the iterator, not just use an iterator loop in place of the for-each loop, which is how I read your comment. Seems like you could add an answer... (ah you did). Incidentally, you do not need two threads to iterate through the same collection with two iterators.

Comment: @RubendeGroot possible (not the best at all) solution but should get you by for now

Comment: When you added the **Possible Sollution** it worked! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @RubendeGroot no problem, glad i could help :)

Answer (score 2):

You are removing entities in the `tick()` method...  while in the method, you are still iterating over the entities in the outer tick method...  because you're modifying the list inside `e.tick()`, the list is changing, which causes the next iteration to fail...  replacing the method call to `e.tick()` with the inline method demonstrates the problem more clearly:

```
@Override
public void tick(float delta) {
    for (Entity e : entities) {
        //e.tick(delta); --inline below

          if (color == Color.WHITE) {
              if (getSurrounding(-32, -32) != null && getSurrounding(-32, -32).getColor() == Color.BLACK) {
                  if (getSurrounding(-32, -32).getStrength() < strength) {
                      getSurrounding(-32, -32).setStrength(-50);
                  }
              }
          }

          if (!inGame.entities.isEmpty() && strength <= 0) {
              inGame.entities.remove(this); // <------ REMOVING AN ELEMENT
          }
      }

}
```

Note that where you have remarked you are "REMOVING AN ELEMENT" is inside the outer-most loop, that's the cause of your issue.

Edit: Suggested solution as others have advised, try something like this (just showing the removal block):

```
List toRemove = new ArrayList() //somewhere earlier in the code
if (!inGame.entities.isEmpty() && strength <= 0) {
    //inGame.entities.remove(this); // <------ REMOVING AN ELEMENT
    toRemove.add(this);
}
return toRemove;
```

Then in the calling function, after you've finished all your iterating

```
entities.removeAll(toRemove);
```

Comment: @RubendeGroot learn to properly use an [`Iterator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html)

Comment: Edited answer with possible solutions.  I'm not sure iterators solve the current problem as the list is being iterated over multiple times in different code parts, but maybe I'm not thinking correctly.

Comment: where did you find that code block for the `tick` method? i can't find it in the question

Comment: I didn't look closely enough, I thought there was another iteration building a list of elements to remove the boolean return makes more sense.

Answer (score 1):

A solution using an Iterator:

Replace the first code-block with the following:

```
public void tick(float delta) {
    for (Iterator<Entity> iterator = entities.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
      boolean remove = e.tick(delta);
      if(remove) {
          iterator.remove();
      }
    }
    player.tick(delta);
}
```

then replace the other `tick` method with this:

```
public boolean tick(float delta) {
    if (color == Color.WHITE) {
        if (getSurrounding(-32, -32) != null && getSurrounding(-32, -32).getColor() == Color.BLACK) {
            if (getSurrounding(-32, -32).getStrength() < strength) {
                getSurrounding(-32, -32).setStrength(-50);
            }
        }
    }

    if (!inGame.entities.isEmpty() && strength <= 0) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

This should solve your problem. The methods return type has to change, so that we have an indicator when to remove any elements and when not. Every time the `tick` returns true, the corresponding element will be removed

Comment: Block extends the Entity class so that would mean I would have to change the whole abstract Entity class so that the tick method would be returning a boolean, so this solution is to difficult I guess.

Comment: you have given very little information on how these classes work and how the structure is. if you provide more information, we can maybe find a better solution